# execute script only one time until next refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and i am executing a action on the extension icon

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    triggerTab(tab);
 });

var alreadyClicked = false,ct='';
function triggerTab(tab) {
    if (!alreadyClicked || ct != tab.url) {
        addMachine(tab);
    }
    ct = tab.url;
    alreadyClicked = true;
}
```

By this code its only execute script once forever on current tab.. 
I want to run script only once on a tab **until next refresh** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about adding an eventlistener to onUpdated event?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
 alreadyClicked  = false;
});
```

Comment: Working like charm Thank u !